# Issue about the return value of getTime()

Tags: javascript, time

I have created a date variable pointing to 9th of July 2014

```
 var date = new Date(2014, 6, 9);
```

When I try to obtain the time from this date, I expect that the time variable

```
 var time = date.getTime();
```

would give me the value milliseconds value of July 9th 2014 at 00:00:00.

Instead it gives me

```
1404860400000
```

which is the milliseconds value of 8th July 2014 at 23:00:00.
Can someone explain me why this?

Comment: The timestamps are always UST. When you created the date, the system interpreted things in your local timezone. (Are you on "Summer time" somewhere in Western Europe?)

Comment: What changes should I do in order obtain via the getTime() method the 'right' time, being July 9th 2014 at 00:00:00?

Comment: You can construct the date with `Date.UTC(2014, 6, 9)`

Comment: Yes, I am on Summer Time

Comment: @Anto: It **is** giving you the correct time value. What value are you expecting?

Comment: The thing is that I need to pass the long value millisecond value via REST to a resource. The value I want is 00.00.00 and not one hour earlier. When The date is not within the British Summer time period it works, fine, but when it is I have such problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your code here:

```
var date = new Date(2014, 6, 9);
```

creates a `Date` instance initialized to your *local* time of midnight on July 9th, 2014. Timestamp numbers (both JavaScript's milliseconds-since-the-Epoch and Unix's seconds-since-the-epoch) are unaffected by timezones, the value is since midnight Jan 1 1970 UTC.

If you were to construct this date:

```
var newDate = new Date(1404860400000);
```

...you'd have a date that was exactly equivalent to your first one. If you asked it for the local version of the moment it represented, it would say midnight on July 9th, 2014.

In both `date` and `newDate` above, if you ask it the *UTC* version of the date, you'll see it's offset from midnight (the direction depends on where you are, west or east of Greenwich, England). At the moment I'm writing this, almost no one is on GMT, not even those of us in the UK who normally are, because of Summer time. But for most people who are never in GMT, the value will always be offset.

If you want a `Date` instance giving you midnight on July 9th, 2014 UTC (e.g., *not* local time), use `new Date(Date.UTC(2014, 6, 9))`. `Date.UTC` gives you the time value for the given date in UTC, and then if you feed that time value into `new Date`, you get a `Date` for it.

Answer (score 0):

January 1, 1970 :
getTime() Returns the number of milliseconds since January 1, 1970, 00:00:00 GMT represented by this Date object. Returns: the number of milliseconds since January 1, 1970, 00:00:00 GMT represented by this date.

Google.

Answer (score -1):

The Mozilla docs usually cover documentation issues like this quite well.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date